# Как использовать submit ивент JS в моем коде

Tags: javascript, html

Только начал изучать JS и HTML. У меня есть в `html` форма для заполнения и после заполнения нужно соответственно сделать `submit`. при нажатии `submit` хочу чтоб запрашивало если я хочу отправить эту форму. Но даже при попытке вывести `alert event` что то не срабатывает, возможно неправильно написал что то. Если кто то может подсказать как правильно сделать рабочий `submit event`.

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Library catalog</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="mode5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>
          Book Info
        </legend>
        <p>
          <label>
           Author:
           <input name="cusname" type="text" 
                  placeholder="Enter author fullname"
                  autofocus required size="50">
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
           Name:
           <input name="cusname" type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter book's name"
                  autofocus required size="50">
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
           ISBN:
           <input id="tel" name="telephone"
                  type="tel" required size="50"
                  placeholder="Enter 13 digits" >
    <!--pattern="(([0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{4}))"-->
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
           Year:
           <input name="cusname" type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter book year"
                  autofocus required size="50">
          </label>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label>
           Email address:
           <input name="mail" type="email"
                  placeholder="Enter your email address"
                  required size="50" multiple>
          </label>
        </p>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="my-submit">
    </form>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

всё работает...

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  alert("The form was submitted");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Library catalog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mode5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<center>
   
    <form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Book Info
            </legend>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Author:
                    <input name="cusname" type="text" 
                          placeholder="Enter author fullname" autofocus required size="50">
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Name:
                    <input name="cusname" type="text"
                           placeholder="Enter book's name" autofocus required size="50">
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    ISBN:
                    <input id="tel" name="telephone"
                           type="tel" required size="50" placeholder="Enter 13 digits" >
<!--                           pattern="(([0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{3})(-[0-9]{4}))"-->
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Year:
                    <input name="cusname" type="text"
                           placeholder="Enter book year" autofocus required size="50">
                </label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>
                    Email address:
                    <input name="mail" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required size="50" multiple>
                </label>
            </p>

        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="my-submit">

    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вроде да работает... а при открытие localhost не хочет... сейчас еще посмотрю может в другом причина

Comment: а если я хочу чтоб запрос был бы если хочу отправить запрос или нет?

Comment: @RichardWalker значит не так открываете локалхост...может быть сервер не запускаете, не в той папке запускаете или не тот путь в браузере до сайта вбиваете

Comment: @RichardWalker "а если я хочу чтоб запрос был бы если хочу отправить запрос или нет? " --- я не понял что вы написали